# Figures are rotating in both direction with sidewaysfigure option

Tags: rotating, sidewaysfigure

In my thesis, I want few figures to occupy the whole page in landscape. I am using sidewaysfigure option as follows.

```
    \begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=0.5\textheight]{figures/Level_shifter/comp/delay_comparison}
    \caption{A graphical representation of the operating range of the level shifter circuits across different technologies in the last couple of decades}
    \label{fig:comp_delay}
\end{sidewaysfigure}
```

However, all the figures are not rotated in the same direction. It happens mostly in alternative direction as in 90 degree or -90 degree.

Can anyone please suggest a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the figuresright or figuresleft option (see page 2 of rotating manual), or don't use a twoside document class.

Comment: Thanks John. It worked. I used figuresright option.